# generate date out of text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, type-conversion

I am using the bootstrap datetimepicker in my rails application and in order to use it my column type must be a string. But my application requires that I render my date as a date that can be formatted. I need to format my text_field to render out a date that can be changed if necessary. 
here is my code as of now:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
<%= f.text_field :date, class: "form-control", :value => (@event.date.blank? ? '' : @event.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))  %>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: before saving convert it to date..

Comment: @Dylan - You want to show datepicker on text_field?

Comment: @Sontya, yes it is required...

Comment: Try if this help http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars?view=asciicast